# Why does a Markdown string assigned to a variable with `=` render differently from one assigned to an object field with `:`?

Tags: javascript, markdown

I try to render markdown with this library `react-native-markdown-display`.

And then I find a different result when render the markdown content with **equal(=)** and **colon(:)**

This is with **equal(=)**,

```
const exampleMarkdown = `# Hello

**This is some bold text!**

Ordered List:
1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item
`
```

[image]

And this with **colon(:)**

```
const content = {
  exampleMarkdown: `# Hello
    **This is some bold text!**
    Ordered List:
    1. First item
    2. Second item
    3. Third item`
}
```

[image]

Is there any difference between render markdown content with **equal(=)** and **colon(:)**?

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with `=` vs `:`. Those characters do not even occur in the Markdown, but in your Javascript. Javascript syntax has no bearing on how Mardown is rendered. Your two examples render differently because the Markdown in the two of them are different. The first has blank lines, the second doesn't. The lines of the first have no leading spaces, while in the second the 2nd-6th linens are all indented by four spaces, turning them into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is in your strings, not in how you render them. I've taken your strings and put them to https://markdownlivepreview.com/. The result is the same:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have taken my string and the result is same, So the string is fine, right?

Comment: @GandaRainPanjaitan I've taken 2 strings which you think is equals but it is different strings and renders the result differently too.